# No gradient for variables that are multiplied by constant value in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm creating a custom layer that multiplies the kernel by a constant mask value. The mask is not trainable, however the kernel is. But in my implementation, the gradients disappear for the kernel. Any advice on how to make this work?

```
class MaskedDense(Dense):
    #Dense layer defined here:
    #https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1081-L1247
    def __init__(self, units, mask_weight, mask_bias,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super(MaskedDense, self).__init__(units, *args, **kwargs)        
        self.mask_weight = mask_weight
        self.mask_bias = mask_bias
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MaskedDense, self).build(input_shape)
        self._underlying_kernel = self.kernel
        self.kernel_mask = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.mask_weight, trainable=False, name='kernelmask', dtype='float32')
        self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel_mask)
        self.kernel = tf.math.multiply(self._underlying_kernel, self.kernel_mask)
        
        if self.use_bias:
            self._underlying_bias = self.bias
            self.bias_mask = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.mask_bias, trainable=False, name='biasmask', dtype='float32')
            self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.bias_mask)
            self.bias = tf.math.multiply(self._underlying_bias, self.bias_mask)
        else:
            self.bias = None
```

I feed in a mask array for each layer in a simple model like below:

```
mask_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  MaskedDense(128, activation='relu', mask_weight = mask[0], mask_bias = mask[1]),
  MaskedDense(64, activation='relu', mask_weight = mask[2], mask_bias = mask[3]),
  MaskedDense(10, mask_weight = mask[4], mask_bias = mask[5])
])
```

Using this model gives me all `None` gradients. Using the same code for a model built using the original `tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense` layer works perfectly fine.

Comment: What is value of your `mask`?

Comment: @Mr.ForExample it's an array of the same shape as the weight tensor of values 1 and 0